# How to use the same HTML page across multiple URLs except for the value of one variable depending upon URL queried?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, node.js

I have an HTML page as follows

```
<body ng-controller="DashboardDisplay" onload="submit()">
    <div class="container-fluid" >

        {{scope.arr}}
    </div>
</body>
<script>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('DashboardDisplay', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {

    $scope.submit = function(){
        var jsonOb = {"A":"B"};
        $http.post(URL,jsonOb).
        success(function(response) {
            console.log('got it' + response);
            $scope.arr=response;
        })
    }
    }]);
```

Currently I am hard coding the value of the variable `jsonOb`. For different pages ,the entire HTML remains the same except for the value of `jsonOb`. eg if I query `www.xyz.com/page1.html` the value is `jsonOb={"A":"B"}` but for `www.xyz.com/page2.html` the value is `jsonOb={"1":"2"}`. Other than that, the two HTML pages are identical i.e. I am using two separate HTML pages i.e. `page1.html` and `page2.html` to just set the value of one variable,which I think is pretty redundant.

I want to be able to set the value of this variable based on the URL that is being queried. How can I do that?

PS : I am using an express server to host the content.

Answer (score 1):

You could store all your json data into `.json` files and then look for the hash property of the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) object to query the good one : 
For this example, let's assume you've got file1.json, file2.json etc…

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var jsonPage;
if ( hash.length ) {
     jsonPage = hash.split('#')[1]
     }
else {
     jsonPage = 1;
     }
```

Now you can call your json pages based on the value after the html file name i.e `your_url/page.html#2` :

```
var xhr;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
else if (window.ActiveXObject) xhr = new window.ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
if(!xhr){
    checkOldBro(true); 
    return;
    }
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        var jsonOb = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        $scope.submit = function(){...your function}
        }
    };
xhr.open("GET", "file"+jsonPage+".json", true);
xhr.send();
})(this);
```

Note that you can also check for the [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange) event which won't refresh your page.

Comment: The jsonOb is a really really big object. Is this a feasible solution for that as well?

Comment: Any alternative approach for that?

Comment: But how much vary your objects? You could still use this and store every objects on a single page. Or even query for external json file with XHR

Comment: Could show the code snippet for querying the external json file via XHR?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77964/discussion-between-dubby-and-kaiido).